# get-edid always fails, yet ubuntu detects monitor make/model in system settings

Tags: 12.04, monitor

I am trying to writer some scripts to detect what monitor is plugged in and when. I am not sure if I am going down the correct path, but I notice that no matter what I do trying to use 'get-edid' always fails with the following output:

```
sudo get-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.1. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!
Attempting to use the classical VBE interface

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function unsupported
    Call failed

    VBE version 0
    VBE string at 0x0 "O"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Report DDC capabilities

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function unsupported
    Call failed

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Read EDID

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
    Function unsupported
    Call failed

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Error: output block unchanged
I'm sorry nothing was successful. Maybe try some other arguments
if you played with them, or send an email to Matthew Kern <pyrophobicman@gmail.com>.
```

The interesting part though is that if I go to the display settings in Ubuntu, it detects the monitor make/model/size. I am confused as to how Ubuntu is doing this if get-edid always seems to fail.

I have tried a few different versions of get-edid, and I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have two monitors, one is the acer laptop monitor, and the second is a philips monitor connected via HDMI.

I am also using an EFI boot method, I wonder if that has anything to do with it?

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to [don-crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti):

> The human readable form [...] does not come (directly) from your EDID:
>   Ubuntu uses gnome libraries underneath. libgnome-desktop [decodes the
>   edid](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-desktop/blob/master/libgnome-desktop/edid.h)
>   and - via
>   [pnp-ids](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-desktop/blob/master/libgnome-desktop/gnome-pnp-ids.c)
>   - converts the three-letter vendor ID [...] into a pretty name for the display.

[[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67983/get-monitor-make-and-model-and-other-info-in-human-readable-form)]

Comment: Neat! Though, I still am not sure why I am not able to pull this data myself via get-edid. Any ideas on that?

Comment: you could try `xrandr --verbose` to get the raw EDID data

Comment: how could i use the raw EDID data usefully from xrandr --verbose?

Comment: It's no good to you at all because... it doesn't have the edid and is misreporting the monitor.